# i need help in puting intro animation video for my app , i want it to lunch the first 5sec before the app

Tags: java, android

https://youtu.be/ejM49vbUU3c

this is the logo that i want 
and how to set it up for all devices ?
thank you, I appetite it

Comment: run this video in `videoview` in splash screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another activity to your app called SplashActivity, and set the video and play the video in onCreate method of this activity, set an onCompleteListener to videoView and when the playing of video ends start MainActivity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://ir.ugstudio.playvideo/raw/video1");
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a folder named "raw" in "res" folder and put your "video1" in that.